# Text box content of size 255 exceeding Oracle VARCHAR2(255)?

Tags: java, oracle

I have a text box of 255 max size in UI, when I save the form, I am getting error like its Actual size is 312 can only store 255. The Database column is VARCHAR2(255) bytes.

1. How can I check the actual length of textbox in terms of the column length in DB bytes.

I know this issue might be due to character encoding of DB. There is, A. Character encoding that come in the request header B. Character encoding of JAVA String  C. Character Encoding of DB Schema

2. What is the default char encoding when a String is created from UI in ServerSide

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code to see how the string is handled?

Comment: It would be better if you could change your column to VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:5059489513325

Comment: checking the bytes length in java would be I think "some string".getBytes("UTF-8").length